# Clang on Power PC CPU Architecture?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, clang, powerpc

Has anybody run Clang as a C compiler on ppc architecture? I am trying to resurrect an old G4 12 inch Powerbook (867 Mhz G4 CPU) and will install Linux (Debian with a Linux Mint/LXDE front end) on it, I will not run OS X on the machine. It seems fairly closely tied to Intel/X86 architecture. Will it run reasonably well as a C compiler on ppc? I realize I could run gcc but Clang is much more user friendly.

I will be using it purely as a C compiler, will not tap into it's C++ or Objective C abilities. My programs are student level programs (up to a few hundred lines) and so will likely not tax Clang's abilities.

Comment: According to [the manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html): "*clang currently contains some support for PPC and Sparc; however, significant pieces of code generation are still missing, and they haven't undergone significant testing.*"

Comment: IBM XL C/C++ compiler switched to a LLVM front-end for Linux (but not AIX). Code generation still occurs using IBM gear. IBM switched at XLC version 13.1. I guess Clang support has gotten better. There are still lots of opportunities for improvement (from my experience with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an update. I installed Clang 2.7 on Debian Stable 6.03 on a previously retired Mac Powerbook G4. At least with C, and using medium sized (up to a few hundred lines) programs restricted to the command line, it seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you apply this patch if you have clang older than 3.1:

http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20111010/047625.html

Also, note that if your code uses "long double", it will not be built correctly until http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11867 is resolved.